# How to increase height for a custom UINavigationBar class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

**Update**: I ended up by hiding the default navigation bar and added a UIView which looks same as the navigation bar. This may not sound good but instead of patching into the `UINavigationBar` this is good.

---

This is my custom `UINavigationBar` class which I have created to increase the height of navigation bar in my app. It doesn't work for me. Here's the [code](https://gist.github.com/hemangshah/5698f7f1a931922831950319de4caa0e).

```
class PPBaseNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    ///The height you want your navigation bar to be of
    static let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = 83.0

    ///The difference between new height and default height
    static let heightIncrease: CGFloat = navigationBarHeight - 44

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    private func initialize() {
        let shift = PPBaseNavigationBar.heightIncrease/2.0

        ///Transform all view to shift upward for [shift] point
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -shift)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let shift = PPBaseNavigationBar.heightIncrease/2.0

        ///Move the background down for [shift] point
        var classNamesToReposition: Array<String>?
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            classNamesToReposition = ["_UIBarBackground"]
        } else {
            classNamesToReposition =  ["_UINavigationBarBackground"]
        }

        for view: UIView in self.subviews {
            if (classNamesToReposition?.contains(NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder)))! {
                let bounds: CGRect = self.bounds
                var frame: CGRect = view.frame
                frame.origin.y = bounds.origin.y + shift - 20.0
                frame.size.height = bounds.size.height + 20.0
                view.frame = frame
            }
        }
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let amendedSize:CGSize = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        let newSize:CGSize = CGSize.init(width: amendedSize.width, height: PPBaseNavigationBar.navigationBarHeight)
        return newSize;
    }
}
```

All the method gets called except `override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {...}` not sure, why?

Comment: Did you tried to add navigation bar programmatically?

Comment: Create Navigation Controller reference and then init it new reference on NavBar..
You can init navbar with frame

Comment: Hi Malav, thanks for the reply bro. I tried both in UIStoryboard & programmatically but didn't help. I just added a `UIView` by replacing the default navigation bar. This is a good solution for my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
It is not permissible to change the navigation bar object or modify its bounds, frame, or alpha values directly.
```

[Modifying the Navigation Bar Object Directly](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html)

You can use custom view as navigation bar. Customize view as per your requirement(e.g change height) and hide the default navigation bar as

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, this worked for me in Swift 3:

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: "Your custom height")   
    }

}


// MARK: - View life cycle methods

class DVNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        navigationBar.frame.size.height = "Your custom height"
    }

}
```

Finally assign this custom `UINavigationController` class to your `navigationController`.

Answer (score 1):

**layoutSubviews** works as well override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize).
  so do not worry if it is not sizeThatFits called. I checked in  layoutSubviews Navigationbar height are changing.

```
for view: UIView in self.subviews {
        if (classNamesToReposition?.contains(NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder)))! {
            let bounds: CGRect = self.bounds
            var frame: CGRect = view.frame
            frame.origin.y = bounds.origin.y + shift - 20.0
            frame.size.height = bounds.size.height + 150.0
            view.frame = frame
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below

```
open override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let amendedSize:CGSize = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        let newSize:CGSize = CGSize.init(width: amendedSize.width, height: PPBaseNavigationBar.navigationBarHeight)
        return newSize;
    }
```

Might be worked for you.